# Changing text in textView

Tags: android

I am trying to change the text in one of the textview by calling it in a function that is assigned to a button.. However it is not quite working as I hoped. I was wondering if some one could point out why isn't it working?

Here is the "MainActivity.java" file

```
package com.nblsoft.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    String stri = new String("Hellow");
    public void game(View view) {

        TextView textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textv.setText(stri);
    }
}
```

and the "activity_main.xml" file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="@string/Welcome"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/lower_text"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="34dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:text="@string/guess"
            android:textSize="160dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:onClick="game"/>

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ok"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `not quite working as I hoped` doesnt explain the problem that you are facing..what is really happening? any errors?

Comment: also, where is the code for your button?

Comment: you want call `game` when click in EditText?! you put `android:onClick="game"` in EditText !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want call `game` when click in EditText?! you put `android:onClick="game"` in EditText

if want call when click in **Button** you must add `android:onClick="game"` to your Button in **activity_main.xml** file like

```
<Button
   style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="ok"
   android:id="@+id/button"
   android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
   android:onClick="game" />
```

or you can use this in **MainActivity.java** *instead* use `android:onClick="game"` in xml file

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            game(arg0);
        }
    });
}
```

**-** remove `android:onClick="game"` from EditText

Answer (score 0):

```
        package com.nblsoft.myapplication;

        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.TextView;


        public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                TextView textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);    
                String stri = new String("Hellow");
                Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

                btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                textv.setText(stri);
                         }
               });
           }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                int id = item.getItemId();

                //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
                if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                    return true;
                }

                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }


        }
```

This should be working.By the way.Don't rush into android like this...you've got to learn a few things about how it works before you can play with it.Try to check the documentation and play with all that android offers.It's actually fun.It was for me and it still is as I've got to learn a lot ,still.

Answer (score 0):

you call the method game() when you click the edittext "editText", and this will change the textview. If you want to change the value of the textview by clicking button "button", i think you just need to move the game() method to the Button field:

```
 <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ok"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="game" />
```